# How to limit the number of cycles of a loop under some condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, loops, for-loop

I make a loop like this :

```
    int total;
    total = ((toVal - fromVal) + 1) * 2;
    RadProgressContext progress = RadProgressContext.Current;
    progress.Speed = "N/A";

    finYear = fromVal;

    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
          decimal ratio = (i * 100 / total);

            progress.PrimaryTotal = total;
            progress.PrimaryValue = total;
            progress.PrimaryPercent = 100;

            progress.SecondaryTotal = 100; // total;
            progress.SecondaryValue = ratio;//i ;
            progress.SecondaryPercent = ratio; //i;


            progress.CurrentOperationText = "Step " + i.ToString();
            if (!Response.IsClientConnected)
            {
                //Cancel button was clicked or the browser was closed, so stop processing
                break;
            }

            progress.TimeEstimated = (total - i) * 100;
            //Stall the current thread for 0.1 seconds
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);


    }
```

---

Now i want a specific method to run according to `toVal  & fromVal`
in the previous loop but not with the same number of cycles 
i want to to run it in a loop like this :

```
   for (fromVal; fromVal < toVal  ; fromVal++)
    {
        PrepareNewEmployees(calcYear, fromVal);
    }
```

---

for example :

```
fromVal =  2014 
toVal   = 2015
```

so i want to run twice not 4 times! like this :

```
PrepareNewEmployees(calcYear, 2014);
PrepareNewEmployees(calcYear, 2015);
```

but in the previous loop `for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)`

Comment: Why do you do the `* 2` in the calculation `total = ((toVal - fromVal) + 1) * 2` ?

Comment: So whats wrong with `for (fromVal; fromVal < toVal  ; fromVal++)`?

Comment: @RoyDictus : cuz some methods run twice in the finance year in (jan , jul) , for example if `toVal  = 2015 , fromVal = 2014` then
i have 
`7-2014
1-2015
7-2015
1-2016`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand - why can't you just nest another loop inside the first one?

Comment: @Tarec :cuz i want this method `PrepareNewEmployees(...)` to run twice in the previous example not four times !

Comment: Then run PrepareNewEmployees(...) in outer loop and rest of the work twice in inner loop.

Comment: I honestly do not understand what's your intent. Could you explain it in other words?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the point of progress bar updating. You're not supposed to run 4 iterations and do some work every 2 iterations, but the oposite. Do a loop like:

```
 for (int i = fromVal; i < toVal; i++)
{
    PrepareNewEmployees(...);
    decimal ratio = ((double)toVal-i)/(toVal-fromVal) *100;
    //Some other things, that need to be done twice in an iteration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `Thread`'s already, consider to implement following:

```
public void ResetProgress()
{
    SetProgress(0);
}

public SetProgress(int percents)
{
    // set progress bar to a given percents/ratio
    // you will have to use Invoke and blablabla
}
```

Then *any* your *job* will looks like this

```
ResetProgress();
// note: you need to remember from which value you start to be able to calculate progress
for (int i = startVal; i < toVal  ; i++)
{
    PrepareNewEmployees(calcYear, i);
    SetProgress(100 * (i - startVal) / (toVal - startVal)); // in percents [0-100]
}
// optional, required if you exit loop or use suggestion below
SetProgress(100);
```

You can also optimise it, to do not update progress after each step, but after certain numbers of steps. To example, instead of calling `SetProgress` you do

```
if(i % 10 == 0)
    SetProgress();
```

This will calls `SetProgress` ten times less often. Of course, there are some assumptions, like: `i` starts from 0 and if you want to have 100% bar at the end, then `i` should be dividable by 10. Just an idea to start.